# python threading: event vs global variable

Tags: python, multithreading

using global variable

```
event = False
def wait_for_event_timeout(e, t):
    time.sleep(5)
    global event
    event = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t2 = threading.Thread(name='non-blocking',
                      target=wait_for_event_timeout,
                      args=(e, 1))
    t2.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if event:
            logging.debug('got event')
            break
        else:
            logging.debug('doing other things')
```

using threading.event

```
def wait_for_event_timeout(e, t):
    time.sleep(5)
    e.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = threading.Event()

    t2 = threading.Thread(name='non-blocking',
                      target=wait_for_event_timeout,
                      args=(e, 1))
    t2.start()
    while True:
        event_is_set = e.wait(1)
        if event_is_set:
            logging.debug('got event')
            break
        else:
            logging.debug('doing other things')
```

Looks like i can do the same by using global variable

Whats the use case for event?
When do i want to use it over using global variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between the two. When you write

```
event_is_set = e.wait(1)
```

then you are stating to wait for a *maximal* time If, during the wait, the other thread has triggered a change, it will be noted (nearly) immediately. Conversely,

```
time.sleep(1)
```

is an unconditional time. If, during the wait, the other thread has triggered a change, it will be not be noted until the sleep has ended.

The event, therefore, is inherently more responsive than the latter.

Comment: i can see why that can be useful if the wait time is something large. although it seems very trivial difference

Comment: You are correct. However, note that with the global variable approach, you need to find the "sweet spot" where you have a trivial difference in responsiveness, but not too high CPU overhead. Using an event (with a high, or unlimited wait time), gives you this automatically.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the important difference Ami Tavory pointed out,  `Event` is nicer than a global variable if you want to wait without "doing other things" while you wait, since you don't need to use a `while` loop:

```
def wait_for_event_timeout(e, t):
    time.sleep(5)
    e.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = threading.Event()

    t2 = threading.Thread(name='non-blocking',
                      target=wait_for_event_timeout,
                      args=(e, 1))
    t2.start()
    e.wait()
    logging.debug('got event')
```

vs

```
event = False
def wait_for_event_timeout(e, t):
    time.sleep(5)
    global event
    event = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t2 = threading.Thread(name='non-blocking',
                      target=wait_for_event_timeout,
                      args=(e, 1))
    t2.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if event:
            logging.debug('got event')
            break
```

Not having to use a busy loop like this means you can leave the GIL released while you wait on the `event`, which will improve the performance of other threads in your application. Plus the code is more concise and readable.